# Visual Studio 2013 Bug: IntelliSense not listing internal types of a friend assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, .net-assembly, internal

**Problem Definition:** I have a class library project named `IRI.Ket.ShapefileFormat` with some `internal` classes and structures. I introduced another project as a [friend assembly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpUDt.png) to this class library. Then I was able to build my solution and run the program successfully. But while coding, **intellisence dose not recognize those internal types and methods. And if I write them manually, they are not colored as expected.**

I'm working on Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate edition.

[image]

**Edit:** In the picutre above why `Shapefile` (this is the internal class type that is defined in the class library and I'm using it in a friend assembly) is not colored like `DataColumn`? Is this a bug?

**More Strange Issue:** Every time the solution can be built successfully but after a while some errors appear in the error list and say e.g. `Shapefile.Read` is inaccessible due to its protection level! Here is a snapshot (all of these methods are internal). Its strange I didn't know projects with errors may be built successfully :)

[image]

Comment: So are you actually concerned about Intellisense, or about the syntax highlighting?

Comment: @JonSkeet Both of them are not working.

Comment: This is a bug, isn't it?

Comment: It sounds like something very odd is going on. Please try to reproduce it in a short but complete program so that we can try to test it too.

Comment: @JonSkeet I found what was wrong with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found what was going wrong. I had lots of class library project with the same public key. These libraries should be introduced as friend assembly.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Friend1, PublicKey=00240000048000009...")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Friend2, PublicKey=00240000048000009...")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Friend3, PublicKey=00240000048000009...")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Friend4, PublicKey=00240000048000009...")]
```

So I thought it's a kind of hard coding to repeat the public key every time and I make a `const string` variable somewhere and use that in the attribute declaration. However in compile time the compiler was able to access it and build the project successfully but in the design time there was no idea how to resolve it.

```
//somewhere
const string key = "PublicKey=00240000048000009...";
//
```

And then I changed those lines like this:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Friend1, " + key)]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Friend2, " + key)]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Friend3, " + key)]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Friend4, " + key)]
```

**So I changed these lines and used the hard code version and now IntelliSense and Syntax coloring are working.**

Answer (score -2):

If you have access to the build of **IRI.Ket.ShapefileFormat** find the assembly.cs file and add the following:

> [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("name of assembly here")]

Put the name of your project that is assessing the Shapefile class between the string quotes above.
Then your project can have access to **IRI.Ket.ShapefileFormat**'s internal types.

Comment: I actually know about friend assemblies and how it is working.

Comment: I miss-read your question, you said it was working, my mistake.

Comment: I *think* ctrl + shift + r refreshes intelliSense, you can try that.

Comment: no. it shows the intellisence but internal members are not listed